# Scrapy: parse the data from multiple pages(pagination) and combine the yield output in single array

Tags: python, scrapy

What I'm trying to do is to scrape multiple pages and yield the result in a single array.

What I've tried so far:

```
import scrapy


class RealtorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "realtor"
    allowed_domains = ["realtor.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://realtor.com/"]

    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
        "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
        "Sec-GPC": "1",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "If-None-Match": '"d9b9d-uhdwucnqmaT5gbxbobPzbm+uEgs"',
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
        "TE": "trailers",
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/Seattle_WA/show-newest-listings"

        for page in range(1, 4):
            next_page = url + "/pg-" + str(page)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=next_page, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse, priority=1
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        # extract data
        for card in response.css("ul.property-list"):
            item = {"price": card.css("span[data-label=pc-price]::text").getall()}
            yield item
```

which gives me three separate list of prices.

```
['$740,000', '$998,000', '$620,000', ......, '$719,000', '$2,975,000', '$1,099,000']
['$500,000', '$474,000', '$725,000', ......, '$895,000', '$619,500', '$1,199,000']
['$1,095,000', '$475,000', '$700,000', ........, '$950,000', '$995,000', '$639,950']
```

what I am looking for is to get one single list like this:

```
$740,000 - 1
$998,000 - 2
$620,000 - 3
$719,000 - 4
     .
     .
     .
$995,000 - 143
$639,950 - 144
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly resulted in the example list, but let's say you have called one of the functions in the `RealtorSpider` that actually resulted in getting three lists. Since these function uses `yield` to return the value you probably need to call `list` on the output of these function to have a list instead of a `generator`.

I suggest you edit your `realtor.py` file such as what follows:

```py
import scrapy
import json

class RealtorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "realtor"
    allowed_domains = ["realtor.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://realtor.com/"]
    prices = []
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
        "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
        "Sec-GPC": "1",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "If-None-Match": '"d9b9d-uhdwucnqmaT5gbxbobPzbm+uEgs"',
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
        "TE": "trailers",
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/Seattle_WA/show-newest-listings"

        for page in range(1, 4):
            next_page = url + "/pg-" + str(page)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=next_page, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse, priority=1
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        # extract data
        for card in response.css("ul.property-list"):
            item = {"price": card.css("span[data-label=pc-price]::text").getall()}
            self.prices.append(item["price"])
            yield item
        data = [x for y in self.prices for x in y]
        with open("data.json", "w") as f:
          f.write(json.dumps(data))
```

If you edit the file into this file, after running `scrapy crawl realtor` in shell, it will generate a file named `data.json`. This file is what exactly you want. Therefore, you can just read it:

```py
import json
data = json.load(open("data.json"))
data
```

##### Output

```
['$575,000',
 '$399,950',
 '$620,000',
 '$1,150,000',
 '$1,100,000',
 '$880,000',
 '$735,000',
 '$337,000',
 '$759,800',
 '$330,000',
 '$575,000',
 '$740,000',
 '$639,950',
 '$950,000',
 '$575,000',
 '$895,000',
 '$950,000',
 '$675,000',
 '$629,000',
 '$2,000,000',
 '$1,325,000',
 '$714,900',
 '$699,950',
 '$998,000',
 '$1,150,000',
 '$849,999',
 '$999,000',
 '$1,050,000',
 '$750,000',
 '$2,975,000',
 '$1,300,000',
 '$1,350,000',
 '$400,000',
 '$1,349,000',
 '$1,175,000',
 '$1,049,000',
 '$3,500,000',
 '$849,000',
 '$719,000',
 '$734,950',
 '$1,099,000',
 '$769,000',
 '$489,000',
 '$1,095,000',
 '$700,000',
 '$475,000',
 '$450,000',
 '$625,000',
 '$330,000',
 '$425,000',
 '$685,000',
 '$385,000',
 '$649,950',
 '$815,000',
 '$699,000',
 '$525,000',
 '$1,495,000',
 '$325,000',
 '$835,000',
 '$599,950',
 '$1,150,000',
 '$895,000',
 '$998,900',
 '$775,000',
 '$565,000',
 '$750,000',
 '$879,000',
 '$325,000',
 '$1,000,000',
 '$785,000',
 '$725,000',
 '$899,000',
 '$1,095,000',
 '$1,175,000',
 '$815,000',
 '$2,300,000',
 '$950,000',
 '$929,000',
 '$1,249,900',
 '$1,650,000',
 '$1,500,000',
 '$639,950',
 '$995,000',
 '$750,000',
 '$630,000',
 '$999,000',
 '$474,000',
 '$390,000',
 '$485,000',
 '$725,000',
 '$500,000',
 '$340,000',
 '$689,000',
 '$525,000',
 '$650,000',
 '$589,950',
 '$665,000',
 '$725,000',
 '$460,000',
 '$749,450',
 '$1,088,000',
 '$525,000',
 '$495,000',
 '$830,000',
 '$475,000',
 '$999,000',
 '$849,950',
 '$848,000',
 '$480,000',
 '$538,000',
 '$4,585,000',
 '$1,150,000',
 '$1,045,000',
 '$730,000',
 '$630,000',
 '$1,950,000',
 '$899,000',
 '$1,975,000',
 '$1,179,500',
 '$2,100,000',
 '$829,000',
 '$2,750,000',
 '$895,000',
 '$849,950',
 '$619,500',
 '$1,199,000']
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it. Can you please extend your answer or using your solution in the question code so I can better understand it. Thank you.

Comment: @dougj Thanks for the comment. I highly suggest you show the part of the code you run and it results in the output provided in your question. The code you provided is just a class that has never been initialized. Try editing your question, and I will come back and change my answer based upon your code to give you better insight.

Comment: This is the whole code and by running `scrapy crawl realtor` scrapy command it gives me the output of 3 separate lists.

Comment: @dougj Since I am no expert in `scrapy` module, let me take a look at  `scrapy` documentation and come back to you with a better answer.

Comment: @dougj I have edited the answer as per your comment. I hope it's what you need.